# I want to create a game

Tags: python-3.x

My code is here:

```
from random import randint
nombre_a_deviner= randint(1,100)
print(nombre_a_deviner)
premier_essaye = input('entrez le nombre :')
resultat = premier_essaye == nombre_a_deviner 
print(resultat)
```

When I execute the code I always get false. But for example if the number becomes equal to 20 and my first try is equal to 20, I should get a true.
help me please

Answer (score 2):

This is because premier_essaye is a string and nombre_a_deviner is an integer. This should work:

```
from random import randint

nombre_a_deviner= randint(1,100)
print(nombre_a_deviner)
premier_essaye = input('entrez le nombre :')
resultat = (int(premier_essaye) == nombre_a_deviner)

print(resultat)
```

More about reading input in Python 3: [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)